# how to put quote in write function in python

Tags: python

I am totaly newbe.
I try to use a gsm card (Sim900) with a Raspberry and Python 3.

I find some exemples, that need to be adapted.
For exemple, I find that I need to sennd a request like :
port.write(('AT\r\n')
That I need to transform to:
port.write(('AT'+'\r\n').encode('utf-8'))

I am able to send SMS.

Now I try to read my SMS.
If I send:
port.write(('AT+CMGR=1'+'\r\n').encode('utf-8'))
I can read the first SMS in the List.

If I want to read all the SMS, I need to change 1 by 'ALL', with the quote.
But I am not able to see how to do it.
I try a lot of things, but don't find the right way to do it.
To be clear, I need to send: AT+CMGDA='DEL ALL'

Thanks for your help

Comment: If you want to create a string literal which contains single quotes, just enclose the string literal with double quotes.

Comment: You can look at [Python string formatting](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/) options to find your favorite usage.

Comment: Thanks, it's help a lot

Answer (score 2):

You can use either normal quotation marks instead of the ':

```py
port.write(("AT+CMGDA='DEL ALL'").encode('utf-8'))
```

or you can escape the apostrophes with backslashes `\`:

```py
port.write(('AT+CMGDA=\'DEL ALL\'').encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.